# How shall I find the path for `org.junit`?

Tags: java, ubuntu, junit

I searched for junit.jar in my Ubuntu

```
$ locate -i junit.jar                                                                                                                  
/home/homebin/matlabR2010b/java/jarext/junit.jar                                                                                       
/home/tim/program_files/programming/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.9.2.v201404171502/lib/ant-junit.jar                               
/home/tim/program_files/programming/eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030/junit.jar
```

Then I think I have tho choose the third one to specify the path for junit.jar, but I still have the `The import org.junit cannot be resolved` error.

```
$ javac -cp "/home/tim/program_files/programming/eclipse/plugins" MyTest.java                                                          
MyTest.java:3: error: The import org.junit cannot be resolved                                                                          
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;                                                                                                     
       ^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                       
MyTest.java:4: error: The import org.junit cannot be resolved                                                                          
import org.junit.runner.Result;                                                                                                        
       ^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                       
MyTest.java:5: error: The import org.junit cannot be resolved                                                                          
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;                                                                                          
       ^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Update:

`MyTest.java` is under `/tmp`, and its content is

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class MyTest {
}
```

I downloaded http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar, and saved it to `/home/tim/program_files/programming/java/junit-4.11.jar`.
Still get the error:

```
$ javac -cp "/home/tim/program_files/programming/java/junit-4.11.jar" MyTest.java 
gcj-4.6: warning: already-compiled .class files ignored with -C
MyTest.java:4: error: The import org.junit cannot be resolved
    import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
           ^^^^^^^^^
MyTest.java:5: error: The import org.junit cannot be resolved
    import org.junit.runner.Result;
           ^^^^^^^^^
MyTest.java:6: error: The import org.junit cannot be resolved
    import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
           ^^^^^^^^^
3 problems (3 errors)
```

What shall I do? Thanks.

Comment: You need to put path to jar in classpath

Comment: Why doesn javac -cp not work? How shall I add the path to classpath?

Comment: Try `javac -cp "/home/homebin/matlabR2010b/java/jarext/junit.jar" MyTest.java`

Comment: -cp mean classpath :)

Comment: The problem remains. See my addition for what is in my java source file for import.

Comment: I don't know what can it be. Try to chck jar content. There should be `org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.class` file in it

Comment: @talex if it is a junit jar then it must be version 3, OP imports packages of version 4

Comment: well if the jar file is in that lication and it has that exact name `junit-4.11.jar` and the exact code you pasted does not comipile, then I have no idea what could be wrong. I test on windows but i dont think there should be any difference. One hopeless attempt would be to remove the `"` surrounding the -cp argument (but I dont think this will help, this suggestion is itself nonsense :S )

Comment: removing double quote doesn't work. @A4L

Comment: @A4L: what do you meant by "if it is a junit jar then it must be version 3, OP imports packages of version 4"? Do you mean I should use junit version 3, instead of junit-4.11.jar?

Comment: Under `/usr/include/c++/4.6/java/`, I have dirs
`applet`  `awt`  `beans`  `io`  `lang`  `math`  `net`  `nio`  `rmi`  `security`  `sql`  `text`  `util`. Is the error because  there is no dir called `org` there?

Comment: I mean v3 had abother package structure and your actual impots are according to v4

Comment: @A4L: I change my java compiler from OpenJDK 6 to OpenJDK 7 (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243544/what-java-compiler-shall-i-use), but that doesn't make the error go away.

Comment: @Tim the jar file is a zip file, you can open it with your favorite zip tool and brows its content. You'll see the directory structure. Please try to compile with the option `-verbose` and post the output here.

Comment: @A4L: problem solved after I installed oracle's jdk, and use its compiler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243544/what-java-compiler-shall-i-use

Answer (score 1):

With the command

```
javac -cp "/home/tim/program_files/programming/eclipse/plugins" MyTest.java
```

java looks for calsses (.class files) not jars in the direcotry specifyed, this is not how jar files are added to the classpath. You should specify it like this:

```
javac -cp "/home/tim/.../plugins/org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030/junit.jar"  MyTest.java
```

However, I would not recommend using that one, since it comes from eclipse installation, I would download it and put it another location and use that one.

If you have an eclipse project and want to add it to classpath then just do

```
right click on your project > Build Path > Configure build path > Libraries tab
```

then click `add library`, select `JUnit`, next select version and click finish.

Comment: Thanks. I am not using eclipse. The problem remains. See my addition for what is in my java source file for import.

Comment: @Tim most likely you have used `/home/homebin/matlabR2010b/java/jarext/junit.jar` which was suggested by talex, I suspect that it is a jar for version 3, in which the packages were not `org.junit.*` but `junit.framework.*`, try using the one from eclipse or better yet download it from [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Download-and-Install)

Comment: @Tim anywhere you want, for example `/home/Tim/dev/java/libs/` and use `javac -cp "/home/Tim/dev/java/libs/junit-4.11.jar" MyTest.java`  to compile

Comment: How shall I write the import in MyTest.java then

Comment: I downloaded http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar, and saved it to `/home/tim/program_files/programming/java/junit-4.11.jar`. Running `javac -cp "/home/tim/program_files/programming/java/junit-4.11.jar" MyTest.java`, the error `The import org.junit cannot be resolved` remains.

Comment: @Tim I just ran this command `javac -cp "C:\private\test\libs\junit-4.11.jar" App.java` with exact same imports as in the question and it compiled just fine. You may want to add the source of your file in your question for further help.

Comment: Thanks. I posted a minimal version of MyTest.java.